# make slider automate by using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

here is a example
[Click](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemSlider/)
please have a look on this ,I have used this plugin on my website but I am not able to do it automate ,want to make events automated .(do the thing whatever doing on click)
please help me .
the code is available on site
[Code is here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/31/how-to-create-a-simple-multi-item-slider/)

Comment: Provide us some of your code so we can try to help you

Comment: i have mentioned the website in question from where i got the plugins ,you can checkout code from there

Comment: If it works in that website and doesn't work for you, then you definitely have done something wrong. btw, this plugin is designed to do the animation effect only for webkit browsers (like Safari and Chrome), while other browsers will not have the animation effect (just instant-show effect)

Comment: no its working on mine too but the problem is that i want to make it automated ,means if user will not click any of link then its automatically perform click event in loop

Comment: ok, I understood now what you mean, I'll edit my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by simply by triggering the click event on the 'a' element

```
<nav>
    <a id="asd" href="#" class="mi-selected">Shoes</a>
    <a href="#" class="">Accessories</a>
    <a href="#" class="">Watches</a>
    <a href="#" class="">Bags</a>
</nav>
```

Give the 'a' id, so you will be able to find it easily, and then use:

```
$('#asd').click();
```

** for this to work infinitely you can do something like this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('nav a').each(function(i){ 
        var aTag = this;
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $(aTag).click();
            }, 1500 * (i + 1)) 
    })
}, 6100);
```

Comment: i want to make it automated ,its working on click but i want to implement infinite loop with perform click action automatically

Comment: check the infinite loop implementation I added

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have included the needed 4 files, if you forget to include any of them, the plugin will not work properly (and may not work at all):

- jQuery 1.8.3 or higher
- modernizr.custom.63321.js (custom build), it's included in the downloadable file
- jQuery catslider.js (the plugin itself)
- The CSS needed for the plugin (the file name is "style.css")

Place the below into your `<head>` tag, (make sure to replace "my_js_folder" and "my_css_folder" with your actual folder names):

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/my_js_folder/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
    <script src="/my_js_folder/jquery.catslider.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/my_css_folder/style.css"/>
</head>
```

Now the imeplementation is pretty easy (make sure to include class "mi-slider" in the div):

```
<div id="myContainer" class="mi-slider">
    <!-- each ul is a section -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="img01">Boots</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="img02">Oxfords</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="img03">Loafers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="img04">Sneakers</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="img05">Belts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="img06">Hats &amp; Caps</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="img07">Sunglasses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt="img08">Scarves</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/9.jpg" alt="img09">Casual</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/10.jpg" alt="img10">Luxury</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/11.jpg" alt="img11">Sport</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/12.jpg" alt="img12">Carry-Ons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/13.jpg" alt="img13">Duffel Bags</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/14.jpg" alt="img14">Laptop Bags</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/15.jpg" alt="img15">Briefcases</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- the nav tag is the lower clickable links. the 1st link shows the 1st ul section, the 2nd link shows the 2nd ul section.. etc. So if you have 5 ul's, you must have 5 links in the nav tag -->
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Shoes</a>
        <a href="#">Accessories</a>
        <a href="#">Watches</a>
        <a href="#">Bags</a>
    </nav>
</div>
<script>
    // make sure the "myContainer" id in the script is the same id of the div
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myContainer').catslider(); // this is the piece of code that will do the magic thing
    });
</script>
```

This a good-looking plugin, but it's badly designed, I strongly don't recommend this plugin!

**Edit:**

Simply, do this in the document ready:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mi-slider').catslider();
        // the automated effect
        setInterval(function() {
            if($('nav a.mi-selected').nextAll('a:first').length > 0) {
                $('nav a.mi-selected').nextAll('a:first').click();
            } else {
                $('nav a:first').click();
            }
        }, 3000);// 3000 = auotmate every 3 seconds
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If so, please tick my answer as correct, you've selected Tomzan's answer as correct not mine